# Zurb Foundation 5: columns don't seem to be clearing properly

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/w8sDS/

I am using Zurb Foundation 5.  I am trying to create a layout that, on small (mobile) devices, will display as a 2x2 grid.
(on large screens this will all be in one row but with varying numbers of columns for each element, but I'm not worried about that part for right now.  Just keep that in mind, and understand that that's why they are all in the same row in the HTML.)

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="row collapse">
    <div class="small-6 columns">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x400/ccc/000&text=350x400" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 columns">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350/000/ccc&text=350x350" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 columns">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350/ccc/000&text=350x350" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 columns">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350/000/ccc&text=350x350" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

When I view this at small screen widths, I see the first image aligned left, and the remaining three images all aligned right.  Why doesn't this end up as a 2x2 grid?  And how can I fix it so it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I got it, mostly based on dwreck08's answer.  But I added the proper row > column nesting structure and put the collapse class back in so it works.

```
<div class="row collapse">
    <div class="small-12 medium-8 columns">
        <div class="row collapse">
            <div class="small-6 columns">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x400/ccc/000&text=350x400" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="small-6 columns">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350/000/ccc&text=350x350" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns">
        <div class="row collapse">
            <div class="small-6 columns">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350/ccc/000&text=350x350" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="small-6 columns">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350/000/ccc&text=350x350" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w8sDS/2/

Comment: Wow - complicated, but I've tried lots of simpler things and they don't work.  I'm using Zurb 5 - wonder if Zurb 6 would solve problem?